# How to solve "User `postgres` was denied access on the database `.public`";?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, prisma

I use prisma and node.js.

When I called some functions (example prisma.users.findAll()) in docker container I have error `User 'postgres' was denied access on the database 'my_db.public'`, but if I run in local I don't have any problem.

However, my containers are successfully, but when I call any function with database I had an error.

```
My docker file

FROM node:15.13.0

RUN mkdir -p /project/node_modules && chown -R node:node /project

WORKDIR /project

COPY package*.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node prisma ./prisma
COPY config ./config

RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate
RUN npx prisma db push --preview-feature

COPY --chown=node:node ./temp ./temp

COPY --chown=node:node . .

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Also, my db
`my_db | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |` 
prisma settings
`DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@172.17.0.1:5432/my_db?connect_timeout=300&connection_limit=150`

Answer (score -1):

If you can get the same error message by running either of these two prisma commands in your project,

```
npx prisma db pull 
npx prisma generate
```

it means that the error comes from a bad `DATABASE_URL` value.

For example: the user should be `chris` instead of `postgres`.

```
// wrong user
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:passw@localhost:5432/dbname?schema=public"

// correct user
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://chris:passw@localhost:5432/dbname?schema=public"
```

Make sure you have the correct values.